# converting a DEB file to an IPA

Tags: ios

Id like to use some 3rd party software from cydia but a lot of the extensions are in .deb, is there a way to convert them to ipas so i cna use iReSign to sign them with my developer distribution cert?

Comment: Why would you need to sign a .deb from Cydia, when by definition if you have Cydia, then you have a jailbroken device able to run unsigned code? If you "just" want to send it to a non-jailbroken device, be it in IPA or whatever the format, you won't be able to run it: software designed for jailbroken devices almost always use private APIs that cannot run on not-jailbroken device due to sandboxing.

Comment: If you just need to automate the installation of deb packages, you can always use the command-line `dpkg` tool.

Comment: I dont have a jailbroken device, there are some Cydia apps id love to have and the only way to do that is convert them to an IPA and resign them

Comment: As I said, jailbroken software often (if not always) use undocumented, private API that won't work on a vanilla device, because of the sandboxing imposed to apps that are running. By the way, I think IPAs can only contain full-fledged applications and not things such as system tweaks (Winterboard, FolderEnhancer, ...) or daemons (OpenSSH, netatalk, ...) which are common on Cydia. If you succeed, you'll only be able to use "classic" apps such as the Youtube recorder (I don't recall its name).

Comment: By the way, this is not even a programming topic, I don't know why we're discussing this here.

Answer (score 0):

In short, no. A .deb contains a lot more information than what an IPA contains, such as dependencies, post install / remove scripts, and file locations that cannot be installed via IPA. You would be better off installing the .deb, zipping up the .app folder, and converting that to an IPA.